# Accessing a variable name in vue 3 like a class component does

Tags: vuejs3

I have only use Vue 2 with class components. Example:

```
@Options({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
})
export default class Home extends Vue {}
```

However now that it is [deprecated](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/569) I am having issues access variables. I am not sure why I cannot use **this** anymore; I do not quite understand how the template will be aware of the variables and how the void methods can manipulate them.

```
        </button>
        {{name}}-{{age}}
        env: {{ mode }} - My name: {{ myName}}
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {api} from "@/lib/api";

export default {
    name: "Home",
    data() {
        return {
            name: String,
            age: Number,
            mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
            myName: process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit(): void {
            api.getTest().then(
                response => {
                    const testResponse = JSON.stringify(response)
                    this.name = JSON.parse(testResponse).name
                    this.age = parseInt(JSON.parse(testResponse).age)
                }).catch(response => {
                console.log("Error while getting the response", response)
            })
        },

        counter(age: number): void {
            age = age + 1
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

--- update 1 ----

I received some excellent advice from a poster, suggesting I `ref` or `reactive`.

Vue 3 is built with typescript which is why class components were decided to be deprecated. However I am not able to use my gRPC generated type objects, or at least I do not know how at this moment

IDE

[image]

axios

```
export const api = {

    async getTest() {
        try{
            return await grpcClient.get<TestResponse>("/v1/test")
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(url.baseUrl)
                    return res.data
                })
        }catch (err) {
            console.log("error" + err);
        }
    },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So vue3 way of defining component is a bit different than v2 - more like native JS. Here's quick example how you component could look like in vue3. Instead of methods, just create function. Instead of data use reactive or ref.

```js
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue'
import { api } from '@/lib/api'

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      name: '',
      age: 0,
      mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
      myName: process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE
    })

    const submit = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await api.getTest()
        state.name = response.name
        state.age = response.age
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error while getting the response:', error)
      }
    }

    const counter = (age) => {
      state.age = age + 1  
    }

    return {
      ...state,
      submit
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. The reason class components were deprecated were because of better typescript support. I must still be doing it wrong because I am not able to use the generated gRPC TS objects! I updated the question